# "Trapping" boundary layer to reduce skin friction drag?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, friction, drag, aerodynamics, viscosity

One of the propsed ways to reduce skin friction drag is by maintaining laminar flow. But to do this normall requires a low Reynolds number. But a low Reynolds number is in itself a recipe for extra drag.

This concept is meant to allow laminar flow at high Reynolds.

[image]

It removes the slowest part of the boundary layer by directing it into a double skin through a series of slits. It works like this.

1. A slit removes the slowest part of the boundary layer.(sigh)
2. This leaves a relatively thick, and slow-moving, *but laminar* boundary layer.
3. The second slit again removes part of this boundary layer, but because it is in the "shadow" of the boundary layer discussed above, the *effective* Reynolds number rise between it and the first slit is *lower* than between the first slit and leading edge for a given length, so *it can be spaced further*

- the third slit sits in the "shadow" of the second slit's boundary layer, so can be placed at an *even larger interval*.
- and so on.

The idea is that *if* we can create a very thick laminar boundary layer (well, thickness is bad but still) we will have to put in less effort to keep it laminar further down the line.

Would this work?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but.

What happens with the air of the old boundary layer? It is now trapped between **two** surfaces, experiencing friction from both sides. All that air will quickly come to a rest and this impulse transfer will slow the airplane down. In other words: Where there was one boundary layer before, you produced three, two of them producing double the friction because they are now trapped in a duct. Once all that air has slowed down, the maximum possible amount of friction drag work has been performed. Now that air needs to be pumped away and expelled, which costs more energy.

See [in this answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/55438/why-does-a-turbulent-boundary-layer-cause-more-friction-drag-than-a-laminar-boun/55481#55481) how much friction drag drops downstream with a longer boundary layer. This should show that any start of a new boundary layer produces much more friction than the extension of an old one. And since the old one is still there (and soon turbulent), it does only help a small bit that the new boundary layer is laminar.

It is better to keep the boundary layer laminar by continuing an accelerated flow over as much of the surface as possible. Also, sucking away the air close to the wall has been tried and helps to keep the boundary layer laminar for longer, but the internal losses of sucking and ducting that air away far outweigh the gains from a longer laminar run.

Comment: The idea is to remove only the slowest part of the boundary layer (<50% freestream) where most of the work has already been done anyway

Comment: @Abdullah I understand. But there is some energy left which now will be completely depleted. Also, that thicker BL works like lubrication and reduces wall shear, so the further growth of BL thickness declines with longer length. You throw away all those advantages for a new, high-shear laminar BL. Yes, that BL will have low shear as well after a short peak, but needs to be refreshed often. In sum: more shear.